# Ускорение парсинга python beautifulsoup

Tags: python, парсер

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно ускорить парсинг каталогов на сайте? П.с. 80 000 товаров в одном каталоге

```
    all_catalog = ['https://www.wildberries.ru/catalog/zhenshchinam/odezhda/bluzki-i-rubashki']
    for url_page in all_catalog:
        response = session.get(url_page, headers=headers, timeout=10)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
            js_scripts = soup.find_all('script')
            #js_script = str(js_scripts[28])
            m = re.search('ssrModel: (.+),', str(js_scripts))
            data = json.loads(m.group(1))
            totalPage = data['model']['pagerModel']['pagingInfo']['totalPages']
            #print(url_page + " " + str(totalPage))
            for page in range(1, totalPage+1):
                url_catalog_page = url_page + "?page=" + str(page)
                response = session.get(url_catalog_page, headers=headers, timeout=10)

                soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

                for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
                    links = link.get('href')

                    if "detail.aspx" in links:
                        url_detail = 'https://www.wildberries.ru' + links
                        response = session.get(url_detail, headers=headers, timeout=10)

                        if response.status_code == 200:
                            soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
                            js_scripts = soup.find_all('script')
                            #js_script = str(js_scripts[28])
                            ssrModel = re.search('ssrModel: (.+),', str(js_scripts))
                            dataPage = json.loads(ssrModel.group(1))
                            print(str(dataPage['rqCod1S']) + " " + str(dataPage['productCard']['goodsName']))
```

Comment: Например через потоки, сделать пул потоков и помещать в него на выполнение список ссылок: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/78a65c09446f06fb62627264a179000afc979410/concurrency_in_python__threading_processing/multithreading__threading__examples/sync_vs_async__with_requests_and_bs4.py#L36

Comment: Перед тем, как что то ускорять, стоит попробовать попрофилировать. А то может все давно упирается в сеть и потоки могут только усугубить ситуацию.

Comment: у меня, к примеру, одна страница с сайта получается за 0.3 секунды. А значит, только на сетевое взаимодействие уйдет 0.3*80000 / 60/60 = более 6 часов.

Comment: @gil9red спасибо. Как указать максимальное число потоков?

Comment: @KoVadim по большей части думал о многопоточности, т.к. объем данных большой

Comment: Кстати, наверняка там есть мобильная версия сайта, попробуйте получать её, возможно она будет гораздо легче и получаться будет гораздо быстрее

Comment: @patrik, передавать в `ThreadPool`, оно первым параметром идет. По умолчанию, там количество берется от количества ядер * 2

Comment: @patrik, я не уверен, что сайту понравится, когда с него качнут это все. А несколько потоково только усугублят ситуацию. Я посмотрел, там некоторые страницы по 200-300кб каждая. Умножте на 80000... Даже продолжать не буду.

Comment: а там не описка в вопросе? там написано 80000 тысяч, это что, 80 миллионов? Тогда я ошибся на три порядка

Comment: @KoVadim как тогда спарсить все товары из каталогов? У wb api только для поставщиков

Comment: так какой порядок цифр?

Comment: @KoVadim в каталоге https://www.wildberries.ru/catalog/zhenshchinam/odezhda/bluzki-i-rubashki 80 000 товаров

Comment: ага, посмотрел детальнее. В мужском отделе  268 050 товаров...

Comment: думаю, спарсить можно, но скорее забанят, чем это сделаете

Comment: @KoVadim прокси не поможет?

Comment: возможно. Но думаю, будет дешевле договорится.