# Скрыть в исполняемом файле подпроцессы

Tags: python, cmd

я написал скрипт для пинга множества хостов. Собрал в исполняемый файл с помощью pyinstaller. Есть два вопроса:

Как мне сделать так, чтобы в диспетчере задач не выводилось большое количество подпроцессов, их можно как нибудь скрыть?

Приложение грузит процессор до 100%, создавая примерно 100-150 потоков. В какую сторону идти, чтобы улучшить производительность?

Код:

```
def getping(host, result, i):

    completed_ping = subprocess.run(['ping', '-n', '2', host[i]], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    tosplit = completed_ping.stdout.decode('cp866')
    result[i] = tosplit.split('\r\n')[1] + '\t' + tosplit.split('\r\n')[2]


def openthread():
    """
    создаются потоки, передаются в функцию пинга хост, результат и порядковый номер
    """
    threads = []
    for i in range(len(host)):
        tread = threading.Thread(target=getping, args=(host, result, i), daemon=True)
        threads.append(tread)
    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()  # Ждем завершения всех потоков
```

Что я хочу скрыть:
[image: Результат программы]

Comment: 1. Никак. 2. Не создавать 150 потоков.

Comment: Насчет 2. уточную, что нужно использовать пул потоков, сегодня описывал в комментарии как и пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1276261/201445 . Насчет потоков, их нельзя много создавать, обычно их "количество ядер" * 2, т.к. есть физические ограничения и тратится время на переключение контекста между потоками

Comment: Тут мало того, что создаётся 150 потоков, так каждый поток ещё и плодит свой процесс. Итого 150 потоков и 150 процессов, а процессы в разы "тяжелее" потоков. Пингуйте прям из потока, не надо ещё один процесс запускать.

Comment: Спасибо, так и попробую сделать
@МихаилМуругов не совсем понимаю как это сделать, не могли бы вы объяснить?

Comment: Гуглите что-то, типа `Pure python ping`. Я за 5 минут нашел 3 примера: [раз](https://github.com/toxinu/pyping/blob/main/pyping/core.py#L292), [два](https://github.com/samuel/python-ping/blob/master/ping.py), [три](https://github.com/kranonetka/PyScripts/blob/master/Raw%20ICMP/icmp.py).